# Is it possible to 'hold' the information of a Python script and run seperate functions, similar to Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm new to Python, sorry if this question doesn't make too much sense.

I have a script that loads in large amounts of data, and then performs a function. After the function is called, the script is closed. This means that every time I want to run the script, I need to wait for this data to load in. But the function itself only takes a few seconds.

Is it possible that I can have the python script running similar to a jupyter notebook, and then call the function in the script whenever needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can only do so if you run your script line-by-line using a kernel (e.g. Jupiter notebook, Hydrogen in Atom etc.). Otherwise, you will have to read in your data every time you run the script. Maybe you can think of a way of restructuring your data, such that reading it in will be quicker. Maybe only save the clean subset of your data, which you are interested in as a data structure in a .npy or .json file format.